Unable to create an Android home screen widget for my Flutter project
I created a new project with the latest version of the Flutter SDK in Android Studio. I tried following Google's official tutorial to add a home screen widget to my project from the menu, but it requires a minSdk of version 16 to let me create one. I tried modifying the minSdk property in the build.gradle file to 20 (16 wouldn't even let me build), reloaded the IDE, but still no change.
I ran flutter doctor and here are the results:
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.27.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.4602], locale en-GB)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.11.6)
[√] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.96.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

• No issues found!


